# Azure Pipeline: Queue time Agent pool selection for yaml based pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to convert a "visually" defined Azure Pipeline to yaml, but have encountered a problem. With the "visually" defined Azure Pipeline you get a UI similar to below when doing a manual queue:

[image: queue UI for visual pipeline]

Note how this UI lets us select between agent pools at queue time. This is a functionality we use quite a lot. We do this since we have pipelines we use for machine learning for example.

Unfortunately, you cannot select Agent pool when switching to yaml based pipeline. It is simply gone, despite the yaml pipeline not defining the pool or similar.

[image: queue UI for yaml pipeline]

Is there any way for getting the same kind of dropdown box for the Agent pool for yaml based pipelines?

UPDATE: Using a variable for the pool name is possible but also a hassle so not looking for a solution that requires entering the full pool name upon queueing. Hence, either a dropdown box or some other mechanism.

Comment: I have looked into other options with regards to defining a bool variable instead and then defining pool name via that but that does not seem possible either e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible as of Feb 2020. Check out the new [Runtime Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters).

Selecting agent pools from a dropdown is actually their very first example.

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14
```

Comment: nice that looks exactly like what is needed, wasn't aware it was released yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable for the pool:

```
pool:
  vmImage: '$(pool)'
```

[image]

Then, in the yaml editor click on the top right `...` and "Variables":

[image]

There define the `pool` variable with "Settable at queue time":

[image]

Now when you run the pipeline you can change the variable to what you want:

[image]

Comment: I know that, but that is not what I want, the pool names can be long and having to write them is a hassle.

Comment: When I click on the "Variables" and then go to *YAML* tab I can see a drop-down for the Agnet pool, can you see it?

Comment: Sure but this doesn't help with being able to define this on queue time unfortunately :|

Comment: @nietras I don't think you another option right now :/

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i dont think its possible to do that with yaml based pipelines, at least not according to the [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pool).

Comment: how come you think the schema implies this not being possible? You can leave out the pool in the yml file.

Comment: well, because pipeline behaviour is defined by what you put in the yaml. sounds logical, right?

Comment: sure but I can forward variables to yaml and everything in yaml as such is settable via variables, nothing indicates that it is impossible to define a queue time definition of this.